# DXF Import QGIS: Text Components

Tags: qgis, dxf

I want to import several dxf-features. This works fine in QGIS 2.18 apart from text (annotations).

The respective text information is stored, at least in my case, within the point components of dxf features and can be displayed in QGIS by utilizing labels.

I would prefer if the labels would be displayed directly (like in CAD software and even ArcMap) since angles of text do not seem to be stored.

Is there a workaround for showing dxf text components automatically and/or for visualizing text labels at correct angles? (dxf2shp did not help me either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of the Plugin: Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter support **textangles** and other stuff like text size, text color, position (text-align), color, individual text formats
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/

Comment: maybe it also depends on the dxf file: in my case these fields are not displayed using the two suggested plugins. But new since 2.18.2 is the built-in dwg/dxf importer which seems to consider the angles of text correctly

Comment: You're sure to use version 0.5 !?

Comment: You are right! 0.5 does the trick, and even well! Thanks a lot! Since gdal now supports dwg, do you know if the plugin will support the import of dwg as well in the future? amazing plugin!

Comment: I'm nor sure, but i think the new QGIS-Import do not use GDAL.