# Convert dwg (CAD) to shp in any open source GIS software?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, open-source-gis, cad

I would like to do what's needed in a GIS (GRASS, QGIS, etc) alone, no other converters-only.

The process is to read the dwg files that would be located in a folder and read them as shp and perform calculations like snapping later or using a geodatabase to store the files and later export them as shp.

Answer (score 3):

ogr2ogr supports DWG to some extent: http://www.gdal.org/drv_dwg.html

So should be as easy as:

`ogr2ogr shapefile.shp cad_file.dwg`

Comment: And what is this? Just python with the ogr2ogr module? Clarify. What parameters takes and so. Thanks

Comment: ogr2ogr is a command line utility. I don't know if your on window or linux. But the easiest way to use it on windows is to use the OSGeo4W installer https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ , then though the OSGeo4W Shell you can type in the provided command.

Comment: In the shp part u say the name it is going to have after conversion from dwg, and in the dwg part you say the file you want to convert?

Comment: Yep. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `Project -> DWG/DXF import` in QGis?

Comment: i want to open in a loop all the files and then do calculations like snapping, etc . how do you suggest to do it like this? i tried uding that but it just opens the file one by one and it doesn't convert it to shp. i think

Comment: That's an important information, that you want to do batch processing. From the GRASS-tools, try `v.in.dxf`, maybe that helps. When incorporated into a graphical model, you may even run the whole process as a batch process.

Comment: Can it process dwg or only dxf?

Comment: Interface suggests it can process both. You'll have to try.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the conversion **CAD -> GIS** several times, unfortunately, to your request, I performed with the usage of ArcGIS. However, I would like to highlight, that there is always *a part left for a manual work due to the difference between GIS and CAD and humans factor in it.* At least in my case, I worked with data that was acquired through the surveying.

The last time I did it, I have used a feature from **ArcGIS** toolbox, known as

> ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Geodatabase ([CAD to Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/cad-to-geodatabase.htm))

I had lots of buildings, therefore some of them were not converted into proper polygons what they should be. Because of that, I used a function to transform unclosed polygons, i.e. polylines into polygons.

> ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Features > Feature to Polygon

But you have to be careful since some of the polygons cannot be produced because of the distance between starting and ending point of the polyline.

Additionally, I can refer you to [Converting polyline to polygon in ArcGIS Desktop for floodplain map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245862/converting-polyline-to-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop-for-floodplain-map) and [How to close polylines that mark shape of cirque glaciers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92900/how-to-close-polylines-that-mark-shape-of-cirque-glaciers).

With the development of **QGIS**, I can recommend the most common way, which was mentioned by [Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik), to use

> Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer > AutoCAD DXF (*.dxf, *.DXF)

Alternatively, there is a bunch of plugins in QGIS, e.g. [CADDigitize](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CADDigitize/), [Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/), [CadInput](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CadInput/) etc. Can refer you to [DXF Import QGIS: Text Components](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216937/dxf-import-qgis-text-components).

Not sure about [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html). Perhaps [HeikkiVesanto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/16530/heikkivesanto) is correct.